# asp.net MVC created_by, modified_by, created_time, modified_time autoHandling

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I am new in ASP.net MVC, started code-first model
In almost all my database tables I have 4 same fields these are

1. created_by   :not null (user id on creation only)
2. modified_by  :null allowed (on each edit will save last modified by user id)
3. created_time :not null (current datetime)
4. modified_time:null allowed (on each edit will save datetime of last modification)

I want some function to manage it globally at once for all table but with checking like this

```
private function CreatedModified(){
   if(action==create){
       model.created_by = current_login_user_id;
       model.created_time = current_datetime
   }else if(action==edit){
       model.modified_by = current_login_user_id; 
       model.modified_time = current_datetime;
   }
}
```

Please help me with this function and where can I place it. because writing same function in each model construction does not look good.

Comment: which ORM are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while, but in your `DbContext` you could place an override on `SaveChangesAsync`. I'll fix an example with some psuedo code functions.

**Update** I'll try to fix a more concrete example

```
//you can put this anywhere you want
public interface IAuditableEntity
{
    //helper interface. put it on the entities you want to trace.
    string created_by {get;set;}
    DateTime created_time {get;set;}

    //todo: add more properties like 'modified'
}
```

Put this interface on the entity you want to track:

```
//Here you reuse the interface
public class YourTableEntity : IAuditableEntity
{
    //implement members...
}
```

Then in your data context:

```
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    WriteAutoData();
    return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}

//just a helper function
private void WriteAutoData()
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().OfType<IAuditableEntity>().Where(c =>
        c.State != EntityState.Detached &&
        c.State != EntityState.Unchanged))
    {
        //the `entry` is of type IAuditableEntity, so you can access it's members
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            entry.created_by = "your user";
            entry.created_time = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
        else if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            //modified data here
        }

        else if (entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
            //deleted logic here: you are not using this. You could use it to log a delete
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please make it a bit more easy, I am not able to complete this, in which file this code should go what to write in `IAuditableEntity` interface? i am using vs 2017 fw:4.6.1

Comment: @alamnaryab: I tried to make it more easier, let me know if you are able to manage it.